# Reactive query definition with Apollo and Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

i try to call a query programaticly eg:

```
apollo: {
listItems: {
  query() { 
      if (this.listType == "bills") {
      return gql`
        {
          bills {
            billId
            order {
              orderId
              customer {
                customerId
                billingAddress {
                  title
                }
              }
            }
            createdAt
          }
        }
      `;
    }
  },
property
  update: data => data.bills || data.bills
}
```

}

but when i try this, i get this error:

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Invariant Violation: Expecting a parsed GraphQL document. Perhaps you need to wrap the query string in a "gql" tag?

I have follow the description in the docs:

https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/queries.html#reactive-query-definition

Best regards and thanks four help!

Stay healthy

Comment: Do you import gql-tag in this component?

Comment: jep, it works without if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot wrap apollo query in an `if` statement. You can use [skip](https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/queries.html#skipping-the-query) instead. In your example it would be like this:

```
listItems: {
 query() { 
  return gql`
    {
      bills {
        billId
        order {
          orderId
          customer {
            customerId
            billingAddress {
              title
            }
          }
        }
        createdAt
      }
    }`
 },
 skip() {
  return this.listType != "bills"
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, thats help! Stay healthy!

Comment: Hey! I'm attempting to do the same, but unlike him I don't want to use skip, rather have two different outcomes from one query. 
https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-option/queries.html#reactive-query-definition
Says It's possible, but it doesn't work.
```js
apollo: {
  getPhotos: {
  query() {
  if (this.checked) {
   return {
   query: getPhotos,
   loadingKey: "loading",
   }
  } else {
   return {
   query: getPhotosByTag,
   loadingKey: "loading",
   variables: {
    filterTag: this.filterTag,
    },
   }
  }
 },
 update: (data) => data.checked,
 },
},
any tips?